# Query con Entity Framework

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Buenos días,

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en ASP.NET MVC C# que me calcule las horas extras de  un empleado, necesito hacer query que me permita poder traer los datos de una **tabla** llamada **MarcacionesBiometrico** que es donde se almacena los datos que se extraen del biometrico de la marcaciones del empleado, y comparar eso datos con su horario, los datos del horario del empleado se almacenan en una **tabla** llamada **Horario**. Y poder embase de la comparacion saber las horas extras que cada empleado y almacenarlas en una **tabla** llamada **TiempoExtraordinario**. A continuacion dejo el diagrama relacional.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola para poder ayudarte tienes que compartir tú código, mostrarnos donde te lanza error que has intentado. Te invito ha hacer un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y sobre cualquier duda puedes visitar esta [sección de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Suerte

Comment: Hola como dice Gabriel necesitamos codigo para ver que hace hasta ahora tu aplicación. Pero puedes hacer lo siguiente: en tu controlador cuando sale el trabajador e insertas la hora de salida recoges la hora exapta en ke salio y la comparas con la de salida, si es mayor en horas puesto ke unos minutos no cuentan entonces insertas en tu tabla de marcaciones las horas ke trabajó y llamas a otro método que inserte en la tabla horas extras la dif ke te dio esa comparación.

Comment: Hola, no he escrito codigo. Soy nuevo esto de entity y asp.net

Comment: En ese caso te recomiendo intentar algo y despues preguntar, este sitio es para preguntas especificas, no para que te resuelvan tus tareas...